# Is this the correct way to build up a Bootstrap panel?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### Problem

Lines in a Bootstrap panel are not aligning but having looked at the documentation believe that there is nothing wrong in what I am doing. I have checked and believe that the columns, rows etc. are being built up correctly, just the right column is higher than the left as seen in the screenshot below.

### Screenshot

Er, I'm not allowed to post an image. You can see it here http://picpaste.com/Capture-JEsTPIWT.PNG.

### Code

Believe this to be an issue within my Bootstrap styling but will include the complete code just in case.

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Order Totals</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6"><h5>Net Total</h5></div>
          <?php

          if($conn){ 

          $stid = oci_parse($conn, "

            SELECT NetTotal
            FROM Totals
            WHERE OrderNo = ".$_GET['id']."

          ");
          oci_execute($stid);

          while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM)) != false) {
              echo "<div class='col-md-6'>£" . $row['0'] . "</div>";
          }

          oci_free_statement($stid);

          }

          ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6"><h5>VAT</h5></div>
          <?php

          if($conn){ 

          $stid = oci_parse($conn, "
            SELECT NetTotal
            FROM Totals
            WHERE OrderNo = ".$_GET['id']."

          ");
          oci_execute($stid);

          while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM)) != false) {
              echo "<div class='col-md-6'>£" . number_format((float)($row['0'] * 17.5/100), 2, '.', '') . "</div>";
          }

          oci_free_statement($stid);

          }

          ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6"><h5>Gross Total</h5></div>
          <?php

          if($conn){ 

          $stid = oci_parse($conn, "

            SELECT NetTotal
            FROM Totals
            WHERE OrderNo = ".$_GET['id']."

          ");
          oci_execute($stid);

          while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM)) != false) {
              echo "<div class='col-md-6'>£" . number_format((float)($row['0'] + ($row['0'] * 17.5/100)), 2, '.', '') . "</div>";
          }

          oci_free_statement($stid);
          oci_close($conn);

          }

          ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: At the beginning, why don't you use <div class="row"> at the very start? It should be always before col-md-X..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why one is bit higher, than other is your  tags.

Since  tags will design it a bit, changing location to its appropriate style, resulting set a bit more down then normal text would be. Your money amount won't be changed though.